# How does short-circuiting of && and || work in java?

Tags: java

Suppose we use **and** operator such that

```
if (a.enable() && b.enable())
```

so the above statements indicates that both the statements need to be true to proceed

What about the case if `a.enable()` return false, and if we write the statement such that

```
if (a.enable() && (b.enable() || c.enable()))
```

so this above statement means that `a.enable()` needs to be true and from the second part either `b.enable()` or `c.enable()` needs to be true. Either one of them needs to be true to proceed, but if `a.enable()` is not true then the condition fails without any further checks.

Is this correct?

Comment: You could just try it...

Comment: Logical operators. Probably in the first chapter of any programming language book. Too bothered too look it up?

Comment: Why don't you print something at b.enable() and c.enable()? You can check whether it is executed or not.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, `&&` means `AND`, and `||` means `OR`. And they're both short-circuit, so in the following case:

```
if (a.enable()  &&  b.enable())
```

`b.enable()` would not even be called if `a.enable()` returns false.

And in the following case:

```
if (a.enable()  ||  b.enable())
```

`b.enable()` would not even be called af `a.enable()` returns true.

That's what allows conditions like

```
if (s != null && s.equals(foo))
```

which would cause a `NullPointerException` if the operator wasn't short-circuit.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (a.enable()  &&  b.enable())
```

The 2nd condition will be called only if the 1st condition is true.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider explaining how your code works and formatting your answer. As written, your answer appears to be gibberish.

Comment: @RichardErickson Even when you wrote that, it wasn't true. It wasn't "gibberish"; the poster simply hadn't formatted it with a code block or used perfect English.

Comment: @RichardErickson Why do you think my answer is gibberish.

Comment: Two reasons: 1) Your initial question was not formatted correctly and 2) The original post was not written as a complete sentence. As pointed out by QPaysTaxes, I may have been harsh. Perhaps "sloppy" would have been a better adjective. BTW, I'm not the person who down-voted your answer.